# Unable to move the user to initialview controller from the second view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, slidingmenu, swrevealviewcontroller

Im using SWRevealViewController  to create a sliding menu.

When the user presses the bar button of initial view controller, a new second  view controller has to open. The user has to navigate back again to the initial view controller when the barbutton is pressed from the second view controller.

Im using the following code to move the used from second view controller to initial view controller.

```
 SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = self.revealViewController;
    if ( revealViewController )
    {
        [self.sidebarButton setTarget: self.revealViewController];
        [self.sidebarButton setAction: @selector( goBack )];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
    }
```

But im getting the following error message,

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SWRevealViewController goBack]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Following is my goBack method

```
- (IBAction)back:(id)sender {

    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Which view controller implements `goBack`? That should be the target of the button. Right now SWRevealViewController is the target, but it doesn't implement that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually you crated the button and action , but you forget to imeplement the method of `goBack`,

```
-(Void) goBack
{
// do something
}
```

**Update-2**

is not in `goBack` it is `goBack:`

```
  - (IBAction)back:(id)sender {

[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

**full Answer is**

```
SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = self.revealViewController;
if ( revealViewController )
{
    [self.sidebarButton setTarget: self.revealViewController];
    [self.sidebarButton setAction: @selector( goBack: )];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
}


  - (IBAction)back:(id)sender {

[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

**edit answer**

```
SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = self.revealViewController;
if ( revealViewController )
{
    [self.sidebarButton setTarget: self.revealViewController];
    [self.sidebarButton setAction: @selector( revealToggle: )];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
}
```

Comment: No bro... I have declared it but still it crases

Comment: can you update the question at the same time are you implemented the revealViewController.delegate = self;

Comment: where should i implement revealViewController.delegate = self;

Comment: @user22312412 - check the full answer and updated2 answer bro,

Comment: Im getting `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SWRevealViewController goBack:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: Its not moving to the initial view controller from the second view controller when i tried it bro

Comment: when the side bar button is pressed from the second view controller, it has to move to initial view controller

Comment: @user22312412 - SWL has seperate Root , is does not under embed with navigartion

Comment: is there any ways through which I can implement it?

Comment: use present or dismiss viewcontroller action bro

Comment: Can you please explain further? :)

Comment: its exactly same as whats in http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/

Comment: Over there second view controller has got sliding menu but I want it to have a back button